# qt thread file not found

Tags: multithreading, qt, file-not-found

fatal error: 'thread' file not found

this is main.cpp.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QMainWindow w;
w.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

this is pro file.

```
QT       += core gui opengl
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = empty
TEMPLATE = app
DEFINES += CC_TARGET_QT5
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

a strange question. why ?

Comment: What version of Qt?  What compiler and version are you using with it?  If you make a simple program outside Qt including `thread` and try to compile it with that compiler, does it work?

Comment: Sounds like your compiler doesn't support C++11's std::thread.  If that's the case, why not just use QThread?